# When performing a left join in spark sql, It is not getting the value properly

Tags: sql, apache-spark, left-join

```
sqlContext.sql("select id, city, value from A").show()
+----+-------+-------+
| id | city  | value |
+----+-------+-------+
| id1| city1 |  4.0  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

```
sqlContext.sql("select id, city, rate from B").show()
+----+-------+-------+
| id | city  | rate  |
+----+-------+-------+
| id1| city1 |  1.0  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

```
sqlContext.sql("""
  select 
      a.id as a_id
    , b.id as b_id
    , a.city as a_city
    , b.city as b_city
    , a.value
    , b.rate
  from A a left join B b
  on    a.id = b.id  and a.city= b.city

""").show()

+------+------+---=----+--------+-------+------+
| a_id | b_id | a_city | b_city | value | rate |
+------+------+---=----+--------+-------+------+
| id1  | id1  | city1  | city1  | 4.0   | 0.0  |
+------+------+---=----+--------+-------+------+
```

b.rate should be **1.0**. but it is 0.0

it is working in spark 2.3 but not in spark 3.1

`left outer join` is not working too.

Looks like a version problem, I looked at the release note, but couldn't find a suitable explanation.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the join! that's a weird thing happening. specially when you say it works in spark 2.3. I would report this in spark , ans see what they have to say